# Trigger hover-like tooltip in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop an extension functionality where user can request a type of given expression by a pressing a combination of keys instead of just hovering.

The key moment here is that when the same combination is pressed again, I want to increase the scope of selection and show the type of the "bigger" block, etc.

I have the functionality ready in my language client, so I have a command and receive the response. I can also decorate the expression I want to display type for, this works well.
But how do I implement triggering hover-like tooltip to actually show the type?